# Incompatible types in assignment with struct's data (same type!)

Tags: c++, c, struct

I have a struct:

```
struct record {
  char team[40];
}
```

And I try to copy its attribute to another stuct.

```
struct record rec2;
struct record rec;

rec.team = rec2.team;
```

Except, I get the following compile-time error on the `rec.team = rec2.team` line:

```
error: incompatible types in assignment
```

The same problem occurs if I hard-code the values.

My understanding is that this is not possible, but it is clearly happening anyway. I would appreciate any insight into what is happening here.

Comment: Your use of `struct record rec2;` and use of `char team[40];` seems to imply C and not C++. Pick a language, since the answer to this question would be very different.

Comment: @Adam Varhegyi: In many cases lone arrays are wrapped into `struct` types specifically to support assignment. In your example, it is possible to assign `rec2` to `rec`, but it is impossible to assign `rec2.team` to `rec.team` (which is what you are trying to do). Arrays are not assignable by themselves.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays aren't assignable.

Assuming you're really using C++, one obvious alternative would be to use a `std::vector` or `std::string`, either of which is assignable.

If you can't do that, you can create some class as a wrapper around your array, then include an instance of that class in your `record`. As Jonathan Leffler was kind enough to remind us, wrapping the array in a struct makes it assignable, even though the array by itself isn't.

If you can't do that for some reason, you can use `std::copy` (in C++) or `memcpy` (in C) to copy the contents of the array. At least in my opinion, this should definitely be your last choice though, as it puts the burden of correctly copying the data from one field to another on the user of the code, instead of letting the code make it easy for the user.

Comment: This is more complicated than necessary. You can assign structures, even structures that contain arrays, even though you can't assign arrays directly.  Thus `rec = rec2;` is simple, safe, sane, and language-neutral (it works in both C and C++).  There are times when structure assignment isn't correct (when the structure contains pointers, for example), but that is not a problem here.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Good point. Not sure what I was thinking when I wrote that, but it wasn't really a particularly good answer as it was.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays have no the copy assignment operator. So you should copy one array into another. In your case you could simply assign one structure another structure that is you could simply write

```
rec = rec2;
```

As it seems you are using C code then that to copy arrays you should use standard function `memcpy` declared in header `<string.h>`

For example

```
memcpy( rec.team, rec2.team, 40 );
```

Or if the arrays contain strings then you could use function `strcpy` or `strncpy`. For example

```
strcpy( rec.team, rec2.team );
```

If you are using C++ then you also could use standard function `std::strcpy` or `std::strncpy` because the arrays are public data members of the structure. There is no any need to declare a constructor. 
The other way is to use standard class `std::array`. For example

```
#include <array>

struct record{

std::array<char, 40> team;

};

record rec, rec2;
//.. some other code

rec = rec2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that when declaring some `type a[N]` array:

1. You cannot set `a` to a different value
2. The value of `a` is equal to the address of `a`

Unlike other types of variables, an array does **not** have an *l-value*.

So in essence, you can consider the **name** of an array as a constant label.

---

If you want to copy the **contents** of one array into another, then you can either use any standard memory-copy routine, or implement it yourself.

**Example #1:**

```
memcpy(rec.team,rec2.team,40*sizeof(char));
```

**Example #2:**

```
for (int i=0; i<40; i++)
    rec.team[i] = rec2.team[i];
```

Comment: Note that `(void *)a == (void *)&a`, but the type of `a` alone is 'array of size `N` of type `type`' whereas the type of `&a` is 'pointer to array of size `N` of type `type`'. In most contexts (but not, for example, `sizeof`), `a` is automatically changed (decays) to 'pointer to type `type`'.  In example 1, you could use `sizeof(rec.team)` or `sizeof(rec2.team)` in place of `40 * sizeof(char)` -- and then you could change the size of the array without needing to change any more code.  Similarly, using 40 in example 2 is not a good idea.  And then there's the fact that `rec = rec2;` works fine.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Thanks. For the first note, your point was taken, and I slightly changed the description at the beginning of the answer. As for the rest, the purpose of my answer was to emphasize the difference between arrays and other types of variables, not to give the most correct way to code it (hence the title **Example**).

Comment: Thanks for revising the first part.  In general, examples should demonstrate best practices because of the [Cargo Cult Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) propensity of people.  When the best practices are very convoluted, a simple example is fine. When the best practice is no more complex than the non-best practice (as here), it is better to show the best practice, even if you don't explain it.  That way, the Cargo Cultists will be partially protected from themselves, even without knowing it is happening.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Thanks. The true reason for not using `sizeof`, is the same dilemma I have myself every time I use `memcpy` (or even the `for` loop). You see - one has to choose which of the two variables to "put inside" the `sizeof`. Technically it doesn't matter of course. But whoever looks into the code may find themselves confused as to why one variable was chosen over the other. Now, this notion becomes even stronger for this particular question, as OP appears to be quite new to all this. So I tried to keep the coding examples as clear and simple as possible.

Comment: I understand that reservation about using one variable or the other.  The other option, then, is to use `sizeof(struct record)`; as long as both variables are of the same type, it is good, and if they aren't the same type, you've got bigger problems.